# Xtext custom warning suppress

Tags: java, validation, code-generation, xtext, suppress-warnings

I have made my DSL and set some info, warning, and error messages.

For example:

```
 warning('''some message''', obj, package.Literals.LITERAL)
```

Then I exported project(generator made class Main.xtend) into a  *some_name.jar*

Main.xtend contains:

```
// Validate the resource
val issues = validator.validate(resource, CheckMode.ALL,CancelIndicator.NullImpl) 
if (!issues.empty) {
    issues.forEach[System.err.println(it)]
    return 
}

// Configure and start the generator
fileAccess.outputPath = 'src-gen/'
val context = new GeneratorContext => [cancelIndicator = CancelIndicator.NullImpl]
generator.generate(resource, fileAccess, context)
System.out.println('Code generation finished.')
```

Now when I run

```
> *java -jar some_name.jar my_file*
```

The generator doesn't generate code because these info/warning messages.

How can I suppress **specific info/warning/error** messages?

Comment: i dont get that. you must have customized something to not generate on info/warnings in the first place. you also can have a look at configurable issues (ConfigurableIssueCodesProvider)

Comment: so simply adding a filter at issues.empty in your code would do the trick